# Iterate through object list by attribute

Tags: python, object, iteration

I do not need to iterate through all attributes in an object. Instead, I need to iterate through a list of objects, but with a specific attribute.
I have a list, called athleteList, of athlete objects, I want to iterate through the unique IDs for each object. Is there some way to do this, I know there's some way to do a similar thing with dictionaries, where you can iterate through the associated values.

```
for ID (in athletelist).ID:
```

at the moment i'd like it to be one expression, as i just want to check for duplicates and need a truthy value

```
if ID (in athletelist).ID:
```

Comment: That code snippet you present isn’t a thing, no.

Comment: [`map(attrgetter('ID'), athletelist)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter)…?

Comment: That code snippet was not a thing, it was just trying to show the kind of thing i was looking for. Also i tried your map suggestion and used a lamba and it worked, but i saw someone else's set construction approach and implemented that before i saw your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can get around this, either by asserting your list has no duplicates, which you can do using [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set) , or as you mentioned, using a check. Note that both methods I describe can be used before iterating through the list.
**Method 1: Set assertion**
Sets in python ensure there are no duplicate data, which is done by checking the data inside each of your object attributes. On the other hand, this may not suffice in your case if 2 athlete objects share the same ID but have different values for another attribute (such as name). You know your use case best and as such can determine if this is suitable for you; the way to implement this is fairly straight forward:

```
athletelist = list(set(athletelist))
```

**Method 2: Set comprehension and count check**
Slightly more complex, however depends solely on the IDs.
Broken down the steps are:

1. Create a list of unique IDs (ie a set of IDs) found in atheletelist
2. Compare the length of atheletelist against the length of the set of
   IDs
   Your final check would look like something like this:

```
    if len(atheletelist) == len({athelete.ID for athelete in atheletelist}):  
        print("IDs are unique")  
    else:  
        print("IDs are not unique")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that second method was exactly what i was looking for. You've been a great help!

Comment: I took inspiration from your suggestion then I read the python documentation about list expressions for clarity, and I found that I can do this: `if ID in (a.ID for a in athletelist):` to get that single truthy expression i wanted.

Comment: @IfFishThenSticker glad I could help, though I imagined you would use the set comprehension before the loop (other wise you would create a list every iteration). If my answer helped you please mark it as accepted and upvote it :)

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to upvote, but ive accepted the answer. Will making the list every iteration fill memory, or will it just cause a small delay?

Comment: Using any variable will take up memory, if by "fill memory" you mean running into serious consequences and memory issues, that may happen depending on the size of your list. However AFAIK the garbage collector should free up the memory after it is no longer referenced. It will also cause a delay, the length of which is depended on the list size

Comment: thanks, i think garbage collector will prevent any real problems

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with simple for loop in python.

```
for athelete in atheleteList:
    print(athelete.id)
```

we can use getattr to check if object's value exists.

```
class Athelete:
    id=""
    
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id=id
    
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id
    
atheleteList = [Athelete(id=i) for i in range(3)]

atheleteList.append(Athelete(id=""))
atheleteList.append(Athelete(id=""))
print(atheleteList)

aab= [athelete.id for athelete in atheleteList
if (getattr(athelete,'get_id')() != "")
]
print(aab)
```

Comment: I was trying to see if there was some way to do it in a single expression, just like how with dictionaries, you can iterate through their values instead of keys: `for i in athleteDict.values()`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to iterate through list of athelete object list if certain attribute value exists. right? I have updated the code, see if it works and it is what you want.

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks for contributing!

Comment: sorry, i can't mark multiple :(

Answer (score -1):

You mentioned in your original post that you would like to check for duplicates within your athlete list.

This can be done by creating a list comprehension where we place all unique ids into a variable and then comparing the length to the total number of athletes. First we gather the total number of unique ids like so:

```
unique_ids = {athlete.ID for athlete in athleteList}
```

Next we can compare the total length of the unique ids to the total length of the athlete list by creating a boolean called *has_duplicates*

```
has_duplicates = len(unique_ids) != len(athleteList)
```

If duplicate ids are present then the unique id list will be a shorter length than the athlete list and as a result will return true. If all ids are unique then the length will be the same and *has_duplicates* will return false.